# Can I know if someone transferred files from my mobile to their computer

Tags: mobile, file-access, sensitive-data-exposure

If someone connected my phone through USB to computer or laptop and transferred files from my mobile, is there any option to check in my mobile that they used particular apps or opened and transferred data

Comment: They can transfer data from the phone only if they can unlock the screen. By default, the USB connection is charging only mode and it requires unlock to switch to USB transfer.

Comment: Welcome to the community. Please also specify which OS you're running on your phone, but the abobe applies to basically any modern OS.